# New custom attribute not showing on catalog

Tags: custom-attributes, install-script, upgrade-script

I already defined a custom attribute "Internal Title" under General Tab.
Now I want to add another new custom attribute but this does not work
Tried with different approaches I found (upgradeand install):

Here is my setup:

install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label'=> 'CustomAttribute_Test',
    'input' => 'textarea',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information"
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'customattribute_test', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Unreal_Custom>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Unreal_Custom>
    </modules>
     <global>           
        <resources>
            <unreal_custom_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Unreal_Custom</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                    <connection>core_setup</connection>
                </setup>
            </unreal_custom_setup>

            <unreal_custom_setup_write> 
                    <connection>core_write</connection>
            </unreal_custom_setup_write>

            <unreal_custom_setup_read> 
                    <connection>core_read</connection>
            </unreal_custom_setup_read>
        </resources>

        <blocks>
            <custom>
                <class>Unreal_Custom_Block</class>
            </custom>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <custom>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Unreal_Custom</module>
                    <frontName>custom</frontName>
                </args>
            </custom>
        </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <custom>
              <file>uecustom.xml</file>
            </custom>
          </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

I also tried to rename my install script to `upgrade-0.1.0-0.2.0.php` and changed          `<version>0.2.0</version>`

If someone could point me in the correct direction, would be great

Best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow belloe steps:

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Unreal_Custom>
                <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Unreal_Custom>
    </modules>
     <global>           
        <resources>
            <unreal_custom_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Unreal_Custom</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                    <connection>core_setup</connection>
                </setup>
            </unreal_custom_setup>

            <unreal_custom_setup_write> 
                    <connection>core_write</connection>
            </unreal_custom_setup_write>

            <unreal_custom_setup_read> 
                    <connection>core_read</connection>
            </unreal_custom_setup_read>
        </resources>

        <blocks>
            <custom>
                <class>Unreal_Custom_Block</class>
            </custom>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <custom>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Unreal_Custom</module>
                    <frontName>custom</frontName>
                </args>
            </custom>
        </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <custom>
              <file>uecustom.xml</file>
            </custom>
          </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1.php**

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$attribute  = array(
    'type' => 'text',
    'label'=> 'CustomAttribute_Test',
    'input' => 'textarea',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => true,
    'default' => "",
    'group' => "General Information"
);
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'customattribute_test', $attribute);
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: Did those steps exactly, but it is not working :/ 

What is not clear to me in first step is following:

1. I did create custom attribute
2. I want to add another custom attribute

Does magento expect an upgrade script (actually I'm not upgrading but adding a new one) or an install script in this case?

Comment: have you  updated "<version>0.1.1</version>"  in config.xml file?

Comment: yes and just to be 100% sure I also copy and pasted everything from your answer

Comment: please check your database table "core_resource"" ver (unreal_custom_setup) updated or not

Comment: There is not unreal_custom_setup in core_resource or anywhere in my db

Comment: But i checked my end all working fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31092/discussion-between-abdul-and-christoph-ha).

Comment: Figure out that the number relies on version number in DB.
so adjusting upgrade file and config file to this version number did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Where are you saving your sql execution scripts? In your case, it looks like it should be: `app/local/Unreal/Custom/sql/unreal_custom_setup/`.